# Identifier "__readgsqword" is undefined - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86-64, intrinsics, memory-segmentation

I'm trying to read memory using the `__readgsqword` function in Visual Studio 2017 and I get an error saying that identifier `__readgsqword` is undefined even though I have already included intrin.h.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <intrin.h>

int main()
{
    __readgsqword(88);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why it says undefined even though it is defined inside of intrin.h

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's only available in x64 mode. If you haven't changed the CPU architecture in the solution, it won't be available.

Comment: BTW, even for smaller operand-sizes, MS only documents these intrinsics for 64-bit mode.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/readgsbyte-readgsdword-readgsqword-readgsword?view=msvc-160. That's weird because the underlying instructions work identically in 32-bit mode.  You'd expect that only `__readgsqword` would be unavailable (because it also requires 64-bit operand-size, or MMX or SSE, to do in a single instruction).

Answer (score 0):

In Visual studio 2022 for using the **__readfsdword** i needed to set the debug to x86 mode to make it work. (i've got win 11 x64)